# Selecting child divs by class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to create a game of memory using Javascript/jQuery. Basically, a random array is generated at the beginning of each game, and the user's task is to match sets of letters. I'm having trouble selecting individual letters from the array.

[Here's a link](http://jsfiddle.net/hj8tm/) to a working example on jsfiddle, but the relevant parts are below:

Here's the html that the array is inserted into:

```
<div id="game"></div>
```

Right now, I'm just trying to implement a hover function that changes the background color of the letter. Here's the CSS:

```
.hover
{
  background-color: #A6977B;
}
```

Here's the Javascript that generates the array:

```
function generateBoxes(gameSize, lettersSize) { 
  var currentLetter;
  letters = randomizeArray(lettersSize);
  rows = gameSize/columns; 
  for (var i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    var row = $("<div class='row'></div>");
    $("#game").append(row);
    for (var n=0; n<columns; n++) {
      currentLetter = letters[5*i + n];
      row.append("<div class='column displayNone' id = 'r" + i + "c" + n + "'>" + currentLetter + "</div>");
    }
  }

};
```

Here's the Javascript for the hover function:

```
  $("#game").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
  });
```

This Javascript code for the hover function works to select all the letters within the array. I only want to select one at a time, however. I've tried replacing `#game` with:

- `#game div`
- `#game .row .column`
- `.column`

None of those options work to select just one letter (in fact, when I use anything besides just `#game`, the hover function isn't called at all).

What is the correct way to select child divs by class here?

Edit: Here is the generated html:

```
<div id="game"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column displayNone" id="r0c0">E</div>
    <div class="column displayNone" id="r0c1">D</div>
    <div class="column displayNone" id="r0c2">E</div>
    <div class="column displayNone" id="r0c3">D</div>
    <div class="column displayNone" id="r0c4">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column displayNone" id="r1c0">A</div>
    <div class="column displayNone" id="r1c1">C</div>
    <div class="column displayNone" id="r1c2">C</div>
    <div class="column displayNone" id="r1c3">A</div>
    <div class="column displayNone" id="r1c4">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can select the children of #game by $("#game").children(".row")?

Comment: Can you post the generated html and also maybe can you put together a working example of it on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Did you try $('.row'); ?

Comment: Also do you need to use jquery for this? Why not just set a rule in the css using the `:hover` selector? `.column:hover{background-color: #A6977B;}` ?

Comment: Same as above: why use javascript for that? Also, are you sure the generated html is correct? You're creating rows, but you always append to the #game div... Shouldn't you create rows, and append "column" divs to them instead?

Comment: @tw16 that works for the hover function - thanks! I do need to be able to select the child divs though for other purposes (i.e. call a function when each one is clicked). I'll post the generated html and edit accordingly.

Comment: @tw16 I'd think it should, but I've tried that and it doesn't work :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're generating your letter divs dynamically, you'll want to bind the mouseenter and mouseleave events to the divs using jQuery's .on() function. Try this:

```
$('#game').on('mouseenter', 'div.column', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover")
}).on('mouseleave', 'div.column', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover")
});
```

Comment: This works - thanks!! Why does using .on() with 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' work but simply .hover() doesn't?

Comment: Because .hover() is trying to bind to an existing element, and since you create your elements dynamically, they don't yet exist. By using .on(), you're binding to any elements that exist now or in the future (you can use .hover() within .on() but I find it easier to read by using the mouseenter and mouseleave events separately which is what .hover() is actually doing). Checkout the docs about [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), especially the section "Direct and delegated events".

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this:

(1) All CSS

```css
div#game div:hover {
  background-color: #A6977B;
}
```

(2) Using Jquery

```
$('#game div').hover(function(){
  $('#game div').removeClass('hover');
  $(this).addClass('hover');
  return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo-class and select on the ID:

```
$("#game").find("div[id=r0c0]")
```